# Displaying error modal on apollo client error using errorLink

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I want to display an error modal whenever there is an apollo client error. For that I tried using errorLink and onError function. But how do we actually render components such as an error dialog centrally inside onError function?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.